# How to resolve Sqlite3 extended error SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK (3850)

Tags: sql, sqlite, qnx-neutrino

I'm new to Sqlite3. I'm using the C++ interface, specifically the amalgamation. The database is being created in a tmp folder with rw permissions, specifically 0x644. When I go to write the table, I get the error SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK (3850). I'm running on QNX os. What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks!

```
bool myApp::Start()
{
   bool retVal = false;
   int rc, ret;
   char sql [] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ZPL_CMDS(" \
                 "id       INT PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL," \
                 "myCount  INT               NOT NULL );" ;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;

   // initialize engine
   if (SQLITE_OK != (ret = sqlite3_initialize()))
   {
       printf("Failed to initialize library: %d\n", ret);
   } else {
   printf("SQLITE3 library Initialized!\n");
   }

   rc = sqlite3_open("/tmp/zplCmd.db", &db);

   if(!sqlite3_extended_result_codes(db, 1))
   {
  printf("SQLITE3: extended result codes turned ONs\n");
  }
  else
  {
     printf("SQLITE3: extended result codes turned OFF\n");
  }

  if( rc ){
      printf("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
  }else{
  printf("Opened database successfully: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  }

   /* write tables */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, NULL); // <-- my code fails here

   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
   printf("SQL error: %s, %d\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db), rc);
   sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
     printf("Table created successfully\n");
   }
```

return retVal;
}

Comment: Does the file already exist? Does a different file name work?

Comment: The file name does not already exist. I've tried other table names and they don't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the locking mechanism under QNX

```
rc = sqlite3_open_v2(path.c_str(), &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE,"unix-none") worked for me
```

The VFS option "unix-none" disables the locking mechanism.

More detail on why here: https://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html